# Print mode command

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I used Zebra Designer to generate ZPL command. The result is like this:
CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~

```
^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR6,6~SD15^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ
^XA
^MMT
^PW900
^LL0600
^LS0
^FT96,261^BQN,2,4
^FH\^FDMA,test 123456^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ
```

Value ^MMT defines the print mode in this case I use "Tear off" mode.

Can I implement this code to print ID card using Zebra XPS series 3? Because print mode is used for label printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time I avoid using printer setting command in my ZPL spool file. So I assume that you are using the "Print to file" from ZebraDesigner.

To avoid erasing the printer configuration with command like ^LL, ^MM, ... , you can:

1 - Disable command setting by using File / Printer Setting / Advanced Setup / Other and check "Use printer setting".

2 - Or don't use ZebraDesigner and develop your own ZPL code from scratch with https://www.zpldesigner.com

Comment: thank you so much for introducing ZPL designer to me :)